# How to change label of mx:canvas at run-time in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, label

In the below code, how could I change the label of Canvas at runtime on collapse of Accordion

```
<components:CollapsibleAccordion id="colap1" >
                    <mx:Canvas id="canvas1" label="Analysis (Ctrl + A)" >
                        <panel:AnalysisByMgr id="analysisByMgr" />
                    </mx:Canvas> 
                </components:CollapsibleAccordion>
```

For example, When I am in Analysis screen then my screen title should be "Analysis" but when I close that screen then it should show me "Analysis (Ctrl + A)"

Comment: What is this CollapsibleAccordion? It's not part of the Flex SDK.

Comment: CollapsibleAccordion is a Container class that creates collapsible vertical Accordion. Please check [link]http://www.flexsamples.com/blog/2009/02/[/link] for more details

Comment: I've only skimmed the code of that component, but as far as I can see your only option is to listen for the `closeDrawerComplete` and `openDrawerComplete` events it exposes. Unless you're ready to dive in and change the component's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting label at run time just set the style of canvas.. it works for me..

canvas1.setStyle('label', 'New Label');

hope it works for you also.

Comment: It worked by setting canvas1.label = 'new' . I didn't try setStyle, but guess that too will work.